# How can I mock this function in jest react test?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

In my jest snapshottest I have:

```
it('should render Alerts', () => {
const component = withTheme(
<AlertsContainer alerts={alertsMock} getApplicants={applicantsMock} />
);
const wrapper = shallow(component).dive();
expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
});

const applicantsMock = [
{
   firstName: 'John',
   lastName: 'Sharma',
   idScheme: 'CustomerInternalId',
   isPrimaryApplicant: true,
   applicantSerialNumber: 1,
   id: '000000797',
}]

const alertsMock = [
{
   taskType: 'Pending',
   taskName: 'Task1',
   subject: 'Review',
   submissionId: 'SUB200620150000875',
   createdBy: 'testuser',
   createdDateTime: '2018-06-14T00:00:00.000Z',
   assignedDateTime: '2018-06-15T00:00:00.000Z',
   dueDateTime: '2018-06-21T00:00:00.000Z',
   applicants: ['16671520038', '16671520039'],
   id: '05025fea-ec37-4767-a868-a646597365d0',
}];
```

In the actual component AlertsContainer I have a function:

```
getApplicantByid = id => _.find(this.props.getApplicants, { id });
```

When I run the test I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'isPrimaryApplicant' of undefined

      121 |         name: a.applicants
      122 |           .map(id => this.getApplicantByid(id))
    > 123 |           .find(applicant => applicant.isPrimaryApplicant).lastName,
          |                                     ^
      124 |       }));
      125 |   };
      126 |
```

How can I mock this this.getApplicantByid(id) call?

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know you can not mock component instance methods.
One thing you could do however is spy on lodash find before your test

```
import _ from 'lodash'
```

In your describe block it would look something like

```
let mock

beforeEach(() => {
  mock = jest.spyOn(_, 'find').mockReturnValue(applicantsMock[0]);
});
```

Additionally you could test if it retrieves the applicants correctly like so

```
it('it retrieves the applicant', () => {
  const component = withTheme(
    <AlertsContainer alerts={alertsMock} getApplicants={applicantsMock} />
  );
  const wrapper = shallow(component).dive();

  expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(applicantsMock[0].id)
})
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: Also, it might be a good idea to just setup your props in your tests which withTheme injects so you dont have to do the dive every time.

Comment: Not sure why you downvoted the answer since it does fix the problem you are facing. Could you please explain why and what I could do better next time? If you need any additional help, I'm always open to take some extra time to reassess ;)